# How to find gaps in Date of the same group of data - mySQL

Tags: mysql, gaps-and-islands

I have a list of dates that have gaps for an execution of a promotion.

```
id       promotion_name  period      value
8495115  Cash_Discount1  2016-11-01  10.00
8495116  Cash_Discount1  2016-12-01  20.00
8491724  Cash_Discount1  2017-01-01  10.00
8479109  Cash_Discount1  2017-02-01  20.00
8459125  Cash_Discount1  2017-03-01  40.00
8491649  Cash_Discount1  2017-06-01  30.00
8491648  Cash_Discount1  2017-07-01  50.00
8491647  Cash_Discount1  2017-08-01  70.00
8491646  Cash_Discount1  2017-09-01  80.00
```

The period in the above table denotes the start date of the execution of the promotion and it runs for a month. 
Hence, the first row means the cash discount runs from 1-11-2016 till 
30-11-2016.

I need the same data in the below mentioned format.

```
promotion_name start_date  end_date    value
Cash_Discount1  2016-11-01  2017-03-31  100.00
Cash_Discount1  2017-06-01  2017-09-30  230.00
```

Whenever there is a gap, that has to appear as a separate row. can somebody please help me with this as any number of self joins is not giving me the result.

i have tried using this for starters but, i am nowhere close to the result.

```
SELECT p.id
     , p.promotion_name
     , p.period AS start_date
     , q.period AS end_date
     , p.value AS spend
  FROM table p 
  LEFT 
  JOIN table q 
    ON p.id = q.id 
   AND p.promotion_name = q.promotion_name
   AND p.period = DATE_SUB(q.period,INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

I am in a situation where i do not know what to search for.

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: What is 'Cash_Discount'? It's very hard to understand the relationship between the data set and the result set.

Comment: @Strawberry: Cash_discount in data set and the result set is the same. i edited the question. if there is a gap in the periods, a new row has to be populated.

Comment: But where's the 'gap'? What's '100'? Why 8495116?

Comment: @Strawberry I assume gaps are the missing months. `value` seems to be the SUM of `value` column in the "island" group. 8495116 is a mysterium for me. OP should be more precise in the question.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel thank you for the interpretation. i have made edits to the output. apologies for the confusions. the id is just a random auto increment in the source data set. that should not be a part of the result set.

Comment: So why does the increment decrease as the date increases?

Comment: @Strawberry: thats the start. the result is no way near. my query i am trying to figure out. i was just hoping that i could find some answers here. i have been struggling with this all day. i have started with a procedure now. if i get any improvements then, i will add on to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
  ts.promotion_name,
  min(t.period) as date_start,
  max(t.period) as date_end,
  sum(t.value)  as spend
from mytable ts
left join mytable t1
  on  t1.promotion_name = ts.promotion_name
  and t1.period = ts.period - interval 1 month
join mytable t
  on  t.promotion_name = ts.promotion_name
  and t.period >= ts.period
  and t.period <= (
    select min(t2.period)
    from mytable t2
    left join mytable t3
      on  t3.promotion_name = t2.promotion_name
      and t3.period = t2.period + interval 1 month
    where t2.promotion_name = ts.promotion_name
      and t2.period >= ts.period
      and t3.period is null
  )
where ts.promotion_name = 'Cash_Discount1'
  and t1.period is null
group by ts.id
order by date_start
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7Xx5bSQmRUGzUCLyB4rKBf/1

The idea of that query is first to find the first row of a consecutive group with

```
select ts.*
from mytable ts
left join mytable t1
  on  t1.promotion_name = ts.promotion_name
  and t1.period = ts.period - interval 1 month
where ts.promotion_name = 'Cash_Discount1'
  and t1.period is null
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fKaNQPkgZqbTfY3Je6Kz4/0

and get the last date of the group with a subquery

```
select min(t2.period)
from mytable t2
left join mytable t3
  on  t3.promotion_name = t2.promotion_name
  and t3.period = t2.period + interval 1 month
where t2.promotion_name = ts.promotion_name
  and t2.period >= ts.period
  and t3.period is null
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hSNZwjDuL1nf2NzPoms5JG/0

Then you need another join with a range condition

```
  and t.period >= ts.period    -- start_date
  and t.period <= (<subquery>) -- end_date
```

and use aggregation over the matching rows.

Comment: Thanks @paul, This is of great help.